# SceneKit -Setting an SCNPlane position glues it to the camera

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I want to create some SCNPlanes to position it similar to the display in the AR Twitter client, TweetReality app.
https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/12/tweet-reality-796x419.png.

I'm using SceneKit as I also have 3D models in my app.

-To get these SCNPlanes to show should I create ARAnchors for each or simply create the node and position it directly?

-If its best to create ARAnchors, how do I create them without the user having to touch the screen? Get the session's current frame and position it?

I'm using this code to place an SCNPlane, however it gets glued, point blank, to the camera whereas if I use an SCNSphere geometry or different its positioned appropriately.

```
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "bubbleBlue")
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    let sceneNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    sceneNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -2)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sceneNode)
```

with the previous code it gets glued, with the following its placed appropriately:

```
    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
    sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "bubbleBlue")
    let sceneNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
    sceneNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -2)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sceneNode)
```

Im using ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, iPhone 6s.

Thank you for the help

Comment: 1st thing to consider is that your setting the width and height of the SCNPlane at 20metres by 20metres...

Comment: sorry my mistake, I'm using 1x1 meters, that was to try and cover up a wall, I'll edit

Comment: Also have you tried rotating  the SCNPlane?

Comment: I've found what was wrong. Thank you mate, by rotating it I found the error. The plane was using the anchor position I set randomly to one of the 3Dmodels I'm importing and since its set as node for anchor it gets glued whenever the anchor is set close to the camera. It gets set to that anchor rather then the the supposed anchor it should have. I' should be able to solve the rest. I'll mark as answered